# Add class to if text contains special word to a div with a class

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I stuck with a simple code but cant figure it out.

Im working on a special form, where you have one select box with a lot of options. This select box is not visible, I just need it to get what the user has picked. The "select box" the user sees is made out of divs and spans. When the user picks an option, the text in an element will show the selected option. The value also changes the selected option in the hidden select box. (I know, its confusing )

This part above works fine. The main problem I got is that different select options show different boxes with more input field. Now I want wanted to show those boxes if the span "selected" contains a special word and add a news class to the box. But many codes I found didn't worked for me.

```
if($('.selected:contains("Eck")').length) {
   $(".d1").addClass("show-form");
}
```

Here is some html from my form:

```
<div class='selectBox'>
    <span class='selected'></span>
    <span class='selectArrow'>&#9660</span>
    <div class="selectOptions" >
        <span class="selectOption" data-value="Rund" value="Rund">Rund</span>
        <span class="selectOption" data-value="Eck" value="Eck">Eck</span>
    </div>
</div>
```

And this box should get the new class "show-form". But it didn't.

```
<div class="box d1">CONTENT</div>
```

Comment: in your given html only one `selected` class span  exist which have no data. so your condition fails and nothing happening

Comment: Is there a script to append some content to `.selected`? If so, post it. Or if it is a plugin, mention which one it is.

Answer (score 0):

what about something like this

```
$('.selectedOption').click(function(){
    $selected = $(this).val();
    switch($selected) {
        case 'Eck':
            $(".d1").addClass("show-form");
            break;
        case 'Rund':
            // do something else
            break;
    }
});
```

Comment: `$(this).val()` won't work, since `this` isn't an `<option>`.

Comment: It should be `$(this).data('value')`